# New to PCB design - why doesn't auto placing components exist?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, design, software, autorouter

The circuit design software I have seen has the ability to automatically route traces etc. on a PCB.
But why doesn't this software have the ability to automatically place components on a PCB say to minimise total board size?
Is this just too complicated to be automated?

Comment: Autorouters should be able to optimally place components based on constraints (i.e. "button must go here", "LED can be anywhere in this area"). They should also be able to select the optimal pins to use on parts that have lots of equivalent pins (i.e. "use any io pin that has PWM"). 

Unfortunately, I have never seen one that does either of these functions. Maybe someday.

Comment: I think Altium has an autoplacer, but some components are meant to be placed in strategic locations on the board and the software has no idea whats strategic and not. And if you minimize total board area, you might make it impossible to route cleanly. I've never used autoplacer and I rarely use autoroute, and when I do autoroute, its for select signals like ground.

Comment: placement (and orientation, gate swapping, pin swapping) is really, really important.  It is the most important thing for getting good routing.  I think a smart autoplacer should start from the schematic placement, unless the schematic is one of those modern "boxes surrounded by netlists" abominations.

Comment: coming from a background thats not circuit design, it seems to me that the rats nest should be enough to layout all the components optimally, perhaps to some constraints. Are most real circuits designed more manually than this?

Comment: Diptrace has autolayout. It's appalling, though.

Comment: In short, optimally laying out components - even without all the considerations that come from it being an actual, non-ideal circuit - is a very difficult CS problem. In fact, it's an instance of the Traveling Salesman Problem, and as such an optimal solution is infeasible.

Comment: Related threads: [here](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/132338/7036) and [here](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/73005/7036).  Both are design reviews of beginners' PCBs that have been autorouted.

Comment: This question leaves me wondering *why* these autorouters / autoplacers are so bad! Why don't people put more research and effort into making them work? (Maybe they do, and all these features are hidden in proprietary packages...?) It can't be that hard to add a little "this cap belongs to these power pins" checkbox...

Comment: @Gregd'Eon I wonder the same. Surely with more work auto-placers can understand the roles of decoupling caps, and simulate circuit noise etc

Comment: @Adam Yep, I guess that's another question we'll never answer. Why does all PCB design software suck so badly that they are only slightly better than pencil+paper?

Comment: @Navin, If you believe that, I'd like to know how many complex designs you've laid out with CAD and how many with pencil and paper?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Software to translate code description to PCB design?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/70818/software-to-translate-code-description-to-pcb-design)

Comment: @NickJohnson: Not infeasible, practically speaking. While computing the truly optimal result is computationally expensive, there are algorithms that can get "good enough" results in a very reasonable amount of time. Getting to within 95%-98% of the optimal solution will cut it for most scenarios. Secondly, depending on how many components, getting the optimal solution may be feasible if you are willing to let your computer run for awhile.

Comment: @whatsisname Yes, you can get good approximations of the basic TSP. This is a lot harder to do with the design constraints of an actual circuit, though.

Comment: @NickJohnson: That part is true, yes, as there is a great deal of important information not indicated to the software in the spec.

Comment: @NickJohnson Comment only: Somewhere in the 10 to 30 years ago range (gives you some scope) I recall reading a report that the TSP had been solved - whatever "solved" means in that context. I'd guess that 'solved' means that an algorithm or method that produced optimal results for a set of constraints was being claimed. | After that they no doubt moved on to the N-body problem :-).

Comment: Even long ago PCD packages had rudimentary autoplace which did NOT attempt to place components optimally but which was useful for stopping everything ending up in a large heap to start with. In ye olde DOS Protel days I wrote a program which  processed the text based schematic output file to relocate and resize component identifiers on the silk screen so that they eg lay inside the component footprint and did not overlay any holes. I used this mainly for two lead through hole axial components such as resistors. Extending that with a rule set to move selected components to appropriate ....

Comment: ....relative locations would be just a matter of doing it. Defining what "it" was would be the hard part. I do not know if more modern software gives you the degree of access to and management of component descriptors and properties that the text based DOS software (quite inadvertently) did.

Comment: @Adam You're underestimating. How does it know which caps go with which component? Which ICs are most noise sensitive or make the most noise and therefore get priority? Or did you just expect it to target the lowest average lowest noise across the board, peaks be damned as long as there are deep valleys so it averages out, and expect it to work? And how did you expect it to simulate noise BEFORE the traces are laid down and without knowing anything about the ICs?

Answer (score 22):

I have been designing some PCBs recently and I would suggest you NOT to use auto-placer or auto-router for your final product. (Proteus has auto placer.)

First of all - Your software is as intelligent as an earthworm when it comes to auto placement or auto routing. In other words, it's dumb as a potato.

Auto routing would not know which placement will get you a better trace pattern which will enable you not only to make an efficient design but also to minimize noise in the circuit. Similarly auto routing doesn't know that shifting a component slightly to the left or right would enable you to route a track in a better way. These tools will just give you a design which is correct according to the circuit. But when it comes to real world performance, things are different.
For example:

- Decoupling capacitors should be physically close to the IC.
- There should be loops of least enclosed area.
- Ground plane should be as solid as possible.
- No interfering signals should be close to your crystal oscillator
  etc.

Your software won't respect these concepts because these are not mentioned in your schematic. You will know only when you have got the PCB manufactured and it doesn't work as expected all the time. I am not saying it won't work. It might work, for 90% of times but you have to take that 10% into consideration too.

My suggestions is that you should learn some PCB designing concepts and try placing and routing on your own. You can always post your schematic and board layout in forums and experts will give you their opinion/suggestions.

Comment: +1 for the earthworm and the potato. Every time I used auto placer and autorouter, I had done the critical bits and left it the easy bit but even that was too much to ask: 60% of the board was placed and routed after the final pass. Better off doing everything ourselves, except perhaps for huge requirements designs with plenty of free space.

Comment: @Mister - Yeah you are right. Even I use auto router every now and then to get an idea for the routing and I finish off the critical sections. However I am using Eagle these days and it doesn't have auto placer.

Comment: Typo in my comment above: "for huge LOW* requirements designs". Obviously, a high frequency digital frequency won't perform well with autorouting and autoplacing...

Comment: I do not see any theoretical reason why an auto-router could not take into account all of the above mentioned constraints and best practices when auto-placing parts. In fact, an ideal auto-router should be able to find the optimal placement that meets these goals better than a human can. It is a hard problem to be sure, but not impossible and I'd bet that soon we will start to see cloud-based auto-routers with auto-placers who can beat even the best humans.

Comment: @bigjosh - Your comment makes lots of sense. Correct routing and placement has a few guidelines which if broken down to simple logic, should enable computers to out-perform a human. All that will be left is maybe trillions of calculations - checking thousands of fully routed boards and figuring out the optimum solution. With cloud based systems, that shouldn't be too hard. Let's hope some open source project starts soon to make this a reality. It might be better than humans in a way that humans don't really go for multiple iterations once they have found a working solution - at least I don't.

Comment: Doing placement and routing on a single layer PCB can waste A LOT of time if you do it manually. I want the application to tell me how to place the components to get the least amount of "air wires" as possible on DIY projects. Of course it should allow me to add constraints, such as fixing the placement of certain components.

Comment: @dan - I guess we all want that feature. However currently no CAD package is providing a reliable solution for the same. Like bigjosh said, it's possible theoretically but as of now, you are better off doing the placement yourself.

Comment: @Whiskeyjack Several programs do have auto-placement and auto-routing. If it is good enough, is for everyone to decide, I guess. I personally place the "important" components manually and let the program place the rest (+ auto routing).

Answer (score 14):

One thing you're not considering is that *a schematic does not contain enough information to lay out a board properly*.

Basically, the PCB layout requires consideration and accommodation for a few dozen layout requirements *per part*, none of which are codified in the schematic. Consider just the bypass capacitors. To have an automated system properly place the bypass capacitor for each component, you'd need to have some additional directives on the schematic that dictate to the autorouter that the trace between the two nodes must be below a certain length.
Presumably, you'd then need further directives to encode the *priority* of length minimization for various nets, something to dictate differential pairs/controlled impedance, guard traces (if needed), etc...
Basically, there are a lot of additional variables that drive the placement that are usually not encoded at all in schematic/ratsnest documents.

Furthermore, even if you assume that you have all of the above design constraints, the sheer size of the problem space for a common layout is **enormous**. It's the equivalent of trying to solve a equation with thousands of inputs, where every input has a different, non-linear effect on all the others. Effectively, the problem is completely intractable from a brute-force perspective. Any solution must therefore involve some sort of heuristic mechanism, which has it's own complexities.

---

Realistically, the primary reason there aren't at least *better* autorouters is that there's just no market. The EDA market is comparatively small in comparison to many other niche, special purpose software markets, and even the best autorouter ever won't even approach a real layout by an actual human.

When in the midst of a particularly boring layout, I usually have some fantasies of trying to design my own autorouter, by doing something with vector fields and simulated annealing, but even that would only approach a local optimum, rather then a general optimum layout.

Answer (score 13):

My router has a placer and support for "rooms".  That let's you draw areas and assign parts to "rooms" from the schematic.  The auto placer will group them together in the room the part is assigned to.  Pretty sure it has support for this connector should go to this location too.  There's also a tool that can do automatic decoupling placement and part selection/optimization based on simulation results.  It's not cheap though :) but it does work.

The auto placer can save you a little time by placing everything together like that.  But I still prefer cross probing the schematic to the layout in place mode.

Just like the auto router you get out what you put in in terms of constraints and how well you can use it.   If you just try to use your auto router without constraining it properly it just routes everywhere.  When set up properly we use it to correctly route large matched length DDR sections.  On much larger and denser boards it's almost a necessity, and certainly a requirement for a layout services shop that needs the speed.  However these things might not be worth it for someone doing only a few small boards a year.

Comment: What's your CAD package?

Comment: The high end version of Allegro, the decoupling is from Sigrity now owned by cadence.  I like pads too.  That new path based auto router thats supposed to look like hand routing looks interesting.

Comment: I had a hunch this might be Cadence. I used it for an introduction to IC design, it is indeed an excellent package and I do believe its autorouter and autoplacer might just be efficient if the constraints are correctly formulated (which comes down to experience/training).

Comment: Well said. Placing parts and routing isn't impossible, it's just much harder and fuzzier than schematic capture. First of all, the circuit diagram is far short of a complete input to auto-place parts. Regular PCB packages are designed for wiring, not auto-placement.

Answer (score 11):

Back in 1974-1975 I worked in the Design Automation department at Honeywell. The problem hasn't changed since then:

1. It's not computationally feasible to optimize. Like most global optimization problems, it's NP-Complete, meaning the complexity of the computation grows horribly quickly. Since you can't wait around for a trillion years (or worse), we can regard the optimal solution as being impossible to find.
2. It's unclear to the program just what you want to optimize. Logical grouping according to your model of the circuit organization? Trace length? Board area? Parasitic coupling? Propagation delay? Thermal dissipation (max temp)? Thermal bleed from higher-power sections to temperature-sensitive components? RF emission? Noise? Mechanical properties (for example, placing more massive components near the mechanical supports? Service characteristics, like not putting on-board connectors closer together than human fingers can manage? External constraints, like connector locations, or fitting within the available space (no conflicts with cases, fans, etc.)

There are AI-based approaches to dealing with problems like this. However, at some point, it is easier for the designer to just try things, and get feedback from the software as to the design criteria he's interested in. Telling AI software everything you know can be an endless, thankless task. Ultimately, the software has to satisfy you, the designer, and your set of tradeoffs.

The best way for this to work, then, is to view it as a collaboration between designer and software, with the designer making the final decisions. The software can provide information about the properties, and can suggest ways to improve a property of interest, and help explore the consequences of a change.

But I predict we will never, ever, see fully-automated layout -- so long as we have humans looking at and caring about the result.

Comment: So much for the Singularity...

Comment: @PeterMortensen Human opinions won't matter after the Singularity.

Comment: I think point 2 is really the only relevant part of the answer. There are many algorithms that can very quickly solve NP-complete problems, with significant problem sizes, to a "good enough" degree with a very acceptable time cost, good enough often being within 2-3% of optimal.

Comment: That's a good point about "good enough"!

Though to be completely technically accurate, we should carefully qualify the word "solve" (as you did).

The cost in CPU and storage WAS a huge problem back then, however. But even though the problem sizes have grown, our computational capacity has grown even more.

Answer (score 9):

My software has a placer. I ran it one time just to see what would happen. It went rip roaring through the board, and got all of the components on it. When I looked at it, parts were EVERYWHERE. The IC was in one corner, and its decoupling cap was in the other. The critical path zig-zagged back and forth across the board.

My point here is placement is hardest part of the layout to get right. First there are the mechanical constraints. The ME/industrial designer wants your connector/switch/pot/LED/whatever other external interfacing component to come off the board at a certain spot. Some components may be too tall to be in certain areas inside the enclosure. There may be parts of the circuit that need to keep a certain clearance for isolation.

Software can be configured to deal with some of these factors, but it will never do as good a job, or be able to visually see problems the way a human can. In a perfect world, if you get placement right, do power, ground, and critical path routing, a quick pass of the autorouter should be able to finish the layout off.

Comment: I like this answer, though it still seems to an extent that the software isnt up to the job it should be.

Comment: @Adam As you get more experience, you'll understand better. The placement process is incredibly complex, and a rat's nest only tells part of the story. Take decoupling caps for example, how is the placer supposed to know where to put those? As far as it's concern, those caps can all be placed together in some arbitrary location.

Comment: Distance constraints seem like a feasible option for that.

Comment: What is the name of your software?

Answer (score 2):

I have used auto-placers before, and they are indeed as dumb as a pile of rocks.  About the only thing you can sanely use them for is for untangling a pile of footprints that all were imported into your board at the same place on it; anything else is simply too much to ask.